# Python Pool with function that has two arrays as input

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I use a module that has a function f that needs two arrays as arguments, in my case these are sets of coordinates x,y. I try two use a pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from module import f
import numpy as np


npoints = 2000 
x = np.linspace(0.1,2,npoints)
y = np.linspace(0,1,npoints)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

x=xx.flatten()
y=yy.flatten()

xy=np.array((x,y))

pool = Pool(8)

list = pool.apply_async(f,xy)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Unfortunately the jobs never start. Not even one. What is going wrong?

Thanks

edit: f may look like

```
def f(x,y): 
return x*y
```

Comment: First, what platform are you on? And which Python and NumPy versions?

Comment: @abarnert NumPy 1.9.0 and Python 2.7.5, Plattform openSuse

Comment: It's better to edit that into the question. Also, it would help if your program were a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, besides not including an example `f` function, it also has at least one `NameError` preventing it from even getting to the pool.

Comment: each apply_async is one process fork.

Comment: Also, as a side note: You're only starting one job, but you say "the jobs". Did you think you were starting 2, or 8, or 2*N? (That shouldn't really affect the answer—the 1 job should obviously be as startable as 2 jobs would be—but it might make you unhappy after you solve this problem…)

Comment: Actually, "it would help…" isn't strong enough; the question really isn't answerable as-is, except to say, "I'll bet there's something weird about that `f` function you haven't shown us", which isn't likely to be helpful…

Comment: Actually saying then: is my code correct if f is like
`def f(x,y):`
  `return x*y`
But as I wrote already, f is a function that takes two coordinates and returns a scalar value, I tested it if x and y are two arrays

Answer (score 0):

your original program only starts on process, one apply_async() is one process fork, you can do this :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
import os

def f(xcoor, ycoor):
    print "worker {}: coord {}".format(os.getpid(), (xcoor, ycoor))


npoints = 20
x = np.linspace(0.1,2,npoints)
y = np.linspace(0.1,2,npoints) #a typo in original program. 

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

x=xx.flatten()
y=yy.flatten()

pool = Pool(8)
ll = []
for (xx, yy) in zip(x,y):
    ll.append(pool.apply_async(f, (xx,yy)))


pool.close()
pool.join()
# not in order
ll = [a.get() for a in ll]
```

output (partly):

```
In [5]: run delme.py
worker 32489: coord (0.20000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32489: coord (0.40000000000000002, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32490: coord (0.29999999999999999, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32488: coord (0.10000000000000001, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32489: coord (0.5, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32490: coord (0.59999999999999998, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32493: coord (0.69999999999999996, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32493: coord (0.79999999999999993, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32491: coord (0.89999999999999991, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32488: coord (1.0999999999999999, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32495: coord (0.99999999999999989, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32488: coord (1.2, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32489: coord (1.3, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32490: coord (1.3999999999999999, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32493: coord (1.5, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32491: coord (1.5999999999999999, 0.10000000000000001)
worker 32492: coord (1.7, 0.10000000000000001)
```

I always find joblib package be every simple and powerful when dealing with numpy. you can check it out. it transform multiprocessing writing into one-line + memoization

Comment: But that can't be his actual problem. Starting only 1 job instead of 2 (or however many he wanted) won't prevent that 1 job from running.

Comment: @abarnert, he/she should say more about what he means by 'never start'.

Comment: thx I think it is a problem with the given function f, I can run the jobs when I define a function that multiplies two coordinates though.

Comment: @fasttooth: Agreed, the question is very hard to answer as written. But I don't think this is likely to be the answer to whatever his problem is.

Comment: Could I use `pool.imap` so that the outputs are in the same order as it would be in serial?

Comment: pool.map returns the result as input order, please google and read the basic doc by yourself.